# Unknown icon on status bar in Motorola atrix 2

Tags: notification-bar, notification-icons

I have found this icon on a Motorola Atrix 2, running Android 4.0.4 and I can't figure out what it is.

I checked the manual but there's no reference to it.

The icon is the first on the left: the white handset with the white squares below.

[image: Status bar with unknown icon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks [like the icon](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201906) for a [telecommunications device for the deaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_device_for_the_deaf).